# Likely orbital period of a moon around an earth-like planet

Tags: moons

In creating a calendar for a fictional world I'm considering the phases of the moon. I understand our moon has an orbital period of approx. 28 days. Is there room for variation if the planet and the moon are similar to ours? Does the distance from the planet govern the speed of the moon's orbit?

Would an orbital period of between 12 - 30 days be reasonable?

Answer (score 4):

The important thing here is how the moon formed.

Earth's moon formed in a scenario explained by the [Giant Impact Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis):

1. Earth, the inner planets and other small bodies coalesce in the Sun's protoplanetary disk.
2. Over the years, they grow from their diminutive initial states to more planet-like sizes.
3. One day, a large protoplanet nicknamed Theia hits Earth.
4. Material from Theia and Earth is ejected out into space.
5. Some of this material falls back to Earth (which contains part of the now-destroyed Theia).
6. The rest coalesces to form the Moon.

This collision could have happened at a variety of angles and at a variety of speeds, and could have led to a variety of outcomes. The angle of impact was only about 45 degrees. A more direct blow could have destroyed Earth.

> Does the distance from the planet govern the speed of the moon's orbit?

Yes. You can calculate it.

Set the gravitational force equal to the centripetal force:
$$F_g=F_c$$
$$G \frac{Mm}{r^2}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
$$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$$
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$
That's the velocity in meters per second. You can then find the period (in seconds) by
$$T=\frac{2 \pi r}{v}$$
Use [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) for everything.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately my maths is not sufficient to make more use of your detailed reply. I am just looking for a rough idea as I try to make the story as realistic as possible - see my reply to Josiah above.

Comment: @HDE why don't you add this into the planet answer?

Comment: @user3082 I'll do that, but I'll add that this is only for perfectly circular orbits.

Answer (score 4):

The phase speed is determined by the time it takes the moon to orbit. [Here](http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/moons_table.html) is a table of orbital periods. As you can see, there is a huge range in the length of "months."

Callisto, for example, is roughly the same size range as our moon and has a 16 day orbital period.

Now, in order for the phases of the moon to affect society, you'll need 2 things:

1. Prominence - the moon has to be bright enough that the phases are noticeable. (Have you ever noted what phase Venus was in?) You also need an object that reasonably large in the sky. Many objects have phases as viewed from earth, but most are very subtle.
2. Regular change - if your days are too short or too long (on the planet), you won't particularly notice the moon. Phases are meaningful because we have a slowly-changing moon that goes through predictable phases that change subtly from night to night. If you have very low rotational speeds on your planet (long days and nights) and faster orbital periods, you'll see more changes during the course of a night, and the phase won't be as important for telling time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do indeed wish for my moon to be large enough to have visible phases, as you suggest. I understand orbital periods can very hugely, but I believe this is governed by the size of the bodies and the distance between them. For example, if I have a moon which appears in the sky to be a similar size to ours, and orbits a planet much like our own, would an orbital period of say 12 days mean that the moon is actually too close to the planet?

Comment: I was about to suggest you apply the formula in the other answer, but noticed your comment. I think 12 days feasible, because you can make the moon significantly smaller and maintain the same "visual" size if it's closer. But you'd want to do the math to see if it's technically feasible.

Comment: For reference, you're looking for a visual size of about 1/2 degree (30 arc-minute), and an orbital period of about 1 million seconds.